# First key press is not working by using react hook form controlled component

Tags: reactjs

I used react hook form for validations purpose. but our code is implemented on controlled components. I went through few examples in google that use default value instead of value.

If I replace the value with the default value after submitting a form. The values in the form are not clearing can anyone suggest to me how to overcome this.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { getIdToken } from '../Utils/Common';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function Roles() {
  const [roleName, setroleName] = useState('');

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const handleRoleName = (event) => {
    setroleName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleAddRole = () => {
    /* api call here after succes i have clear role name*/
    setroleName('');
  };
}
return (
  <div className='g-pa-20'>
    <h1 className='g-font-weight-300 g-font-size-28 g-color-black g-mb-28'>
      {editaddLabel}
    </h1>
    <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleAddRole)}>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12'>
          <div className='g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v7 g-rounded-4 g-pa-15 g-pa-20--md g-mb-30'>
            <div className='mb-4'>
              <div className='form-group g-mb-30'>
                <label className='g-mb-10' for='inputGroup-1_1'>
                  Role Name
                </label>
                <div
                  className={
                    errors && roleName === ''
                      ? 'g-err-brd-primary--focus'
                      : 'g-pos-rel'
                  }
                >
                  <span className='g-pos-abs g-top-0 g-right-0 d-block g-width-40 h-100 opacity-0 g-opacity-1--success'>
                    <i
                      className='hs-admin-check g-absolute-centered g-font-size-default g-color-secondary'
                      on
                    ></i>
                  </span>
                  <input
                    id='inputGroup-1_1'
                    className='form-control form-control-md g-brd-gray-light-v7 g-brd-gray-light-v3--focus g-rounded-4 g-px-14 g-py-10'
                    type='text'
                    placeholder=''
                    onChange={handleRoleName}
                    value={roleName}
                    name='role'
                    ref={register({
                      required: true,
                    })}
                  />
                </div>
                {errors.role && errors.role.type === 'required' && (
                  <p className='plans-single-error'> Role name is required.</p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='from-group'>
              <div className='form-row pull-right'>
                <div className='form-group col-xs-6'>
                  <button
                    className='btn btn-md btn-xl--md u-btn-primary g-font-size-12 g-font-size-default--md g-mr-10 g-mb-10'
                    disabled={loading}
                  >
                    {loading && (
                      <i className='fas fa-spinner fa-spin spinner'></i>
                    )}
                    Save
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className='form-group col-xs-6'>
                  <button
                    className='btn btn-md btn-xl--md u-btn-outline-gray-dark-v6 g-font-size-12 g-font-size-default--md g-mb-10'
                    onClick={cancelClick}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='from-group'>
              <label></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: We cannot see your code from here and no matter how much you "explain" it, there is not much we can do without actually seeing the code you have that "does not work".

Comment: @crashmstr I have added code. I have used a controlled component only but the first keypress that should work is any solution.